# How to install Elasticsearch and Kibana into Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

[Use this link to install kibana with elastic search](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/elasticsearch-and-kibana-installation-and-basic-usage-on-ubuntu-1604/)

Answer (score 0):

```
/* install elasticsearch */
```

1. Download elasticsearch zip file from: https://www.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch
2. Extract zip file.

   /* run elasticsearch */
3. Go to terminal and `cd elasticsearch-6.2.4/`
4. `./bin/elasticsearch`
5. Point your browser at http://localhost:9200

   /* install kibana*/
6. Download and unzip Kibana from https://www.elastic.co/downloads/kibana
7. Open config/kibana.yml and Set elasticsearch.url http://localhost:9200
8. Go to terminal and `cd kibana-6.2.4-linux-x86_64/`

   /* run kibana*/
9. `./bin/kibana`
10. Point your browser at http://localhost:5601

**To get development source code of kibana:**

A. Download Kibana(CLONE)
        https://github.com/elastic/kibana

B. `cd kibana`

C. Install dependencies in Kibana

```
npm install
```

D. Start up an appropriate Elasticsearch

```
npm run elasticsearch
```

E. Start up Kibana

```
npm start
```

Answer (score -1):

Taken from [elastic.co](http://elastic.co) to install elasticsearch/kibana 5.5.2 (current recommended version)

To install elasticsearch

```
wget https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-5.5.2.tar.gz
sha1sum elasticsearch-5.5.2.tar.gz 
tar -xzf elasticsearch-5.5.2.tar.gz
cd elasticsearch-5.5.2/
```

Then to start it up

```
bin/elasticsearch &
```

To install kibana.

```
wget https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/kibana/kibana-5.5.2-linux-x86_64.tar.gz
sha1sum kibana-5.5.2-linux-x86_64.tar.gz 
tar -xzf kibana-5.5.2-linux-x86_64.tar.gz
cd kibana/
```

Then to start it up

```
bin/kibana &
```